# How to simplify this fraction using algebraic logic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Well, I need to simplify this fraction using algebraic logic

$$\frac{(2^4+2^2+1)(4^4+4^2+1)(6^4+6^2+1)(8^4+8^2+1)(10^4+10^2+1)}{(3^4+3^2+1)(5^4+5^2+1)(7^4+7^2+1)(9^4+9^2+1)(11^4+11^2+1)}$$

For resolve this, I think I will use this concept.
If you have:

$$\frac{(2^2)(4^2)(6^2)(8^2)(10^2)}{(3^2)(5^2)(7^2)(9^2)(11^2)}$$

Simplifying, you must get:
$$\frac{3840^2}{10395^2}$$

Because all are terms with same exponent, like:
$$(2^2)(2^2) = 4^2 $$

Aplying this, I get:
$$\frac{3840^4+3840^2+1}{10395^4+10395^2+1}$$

But, its not the same, I resolve the first fraction and I get: 0.0225539...
The second one result in: 0.0186220...

This is embarrassing, probably i´m complety lost, but I need help

Comment: $(2x^2)\cdot (2x^2)$ is $4x^4$.

Comment: Ops, its true, I use a bad example

Comment: Wolfy says 3/133, so a whole lot of cancelling must happen.

Comment: You seem to be missing all the cross terms, ie the terms that come from multiplying numbers which don't have the same exponent.

Comment: More generally, Wolfy says that $\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^m ((2k)^4+(2k)^2+1)}{\prod_{k=1}^m ((2k+1)^4+(2k+1)^2+1)} = \dfrac{3}{4m^2+6m+3}$.

Comment: This might need $x^4+x^2+1
=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)
$.

Answer (score 1):

After using $$x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2-x^2=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$ and
$$x^2-x+1=(x-1)^2+(x-1)+1$$ we obtain
$$\frac{2^2-2+1}{11^2+11+1}=\frac{3}{133}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Factoring this equation can allow you to simplify significantly.

$$n^4+n^2+1=(n^2-n+1)(n^2+n+1)$$

See if you recognize a pattern after applying this for $n=2,3,4...$